# jQuery - select multiple classes including object

Tags: jquery

my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="class1 class2">Text</div>
```

the related jQuery select:

```
var obj$ = $('.class1');
```

How do I select `.class2` as part of object `obj$` without repeating `$('.class1.class2')`? As far as I understand `obj$.find('.class2')` should not work as `find()` not includes the `obj$`?

Thanks.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Not really - he wants to filter a set of elements down according to a secondary filter, as per @Summarai8's answer.

Comment: In fact the question is how to 'filter' already existing jQuery objects by class name, as answered by @Sumurai8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get a subset of the matched elements, e.g.

```
var $foo = $('.class1');
$foo.filter('.class2').css( 'color', 'blue' );
```

Comment: Is he doing right? obj$ , I think this should be $obj